# How to save xml resource file after update?

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I am using C# to append the xml resource file like this.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(Properties.Resources.setup_info);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("data/Ename");
node.Attributes[1].Value = "true";
```

After this i need to save the resource file. But

```
xmlDoc.Save(path);//needs the file path
```

If i give "Properties.Resources.setup_info" throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ResourceWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)  for this task

Here is the sample code from MSDN

```
using System;
using System.Resources;


public class WriteResources {
   public static void Main(string[] args) {

      // Creates a resource writer.
      IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("myResources.resources");

      // Adds resources to the resource writer.
      writer.AddResource("String 1", "First String");

      writer.AddResource("String 2", "Second String");

      writer.AddResource("String 3", "Third String");

      // Writes the resources to the file or stream, and closes it.
      writer.Close();
   }
}
```

below will write xml to resource file `ProjXML.resources`

```
  using (ResourceWriter rw = new ResourceWriter(@".\ProjXML.resources"))
  {
     rw.AddResource("MyXML",  xmlDoc.OuterXml);
  }
```